# How to create a new System.String type with other name?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I try to describe my problem step by step because I do not know how to say it in correct programming terms.

When I use a **System.String** type, I do the following:

1. Declare the type: `Dim Str1 as String`
2. Assign its value: `Str1 = "This is a string"`

I want to create a new type that just like the **System.String** type but in different name. For example, I want to create a **UrlString** type for string like this:

1. Declare the type: `Dim Str2 as UrlString`
2. Assign its value: `Str2 = "http://www.example.com"`

**My question is**: How do I create the **UrlString** type?

**The reason**: I want to create the UrlString type to help me to identify the value of the content. For example, UrlString type means the string is in url format, PhoneString means the string is in phone format, CreditCardString type means the string is in credit card format and so on.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks Marc Gravell and GSerg. Here is the solution:

```
Class UrlString
    Private ReadOnly value As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal value As String)
        Me.value = value
    End Sub

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal value As String) As UrlString
        Return New UrlString(value)
    End Operator

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal u As UrlString) As String
        Return u.value
    End Operator

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Return If(value Is Nothing, 0, value.GetHashCode())
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function Equals(ByVal obj As Object) As Boolean
        Return String.Equals(value, DirectCast(obj, String))
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return value
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: For context - my VB.NET is *also* pretty weak; however, at the .NET level both should work nicely. Apols for the C# example, but I couldn't reliably write VB these days.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing that BTW. Urls are a subset of strings, therefore the conversion operator must be narrowing (non-implicit in C#) and must check that the string is indeed an url. This disables `u = "sadf"` and requires `u = ctype("sadf", UrlString)`, at which point it might be easier to go with just `u = New UrlString("sadf")`, but otherwise you will end up with random crap being treated as an url.

Comment: @ Marc Gravell: Thanks for your code, your code already perfected by GSerg :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add an implicit conversion operator from `string` to `UrlString` for that to work. In C#:

```
class UrlString
{
    private readonly string value;
    public UrlString(string value) { this.value = value; }
    public static implicit operator UrlString(string value)
    {
        return new UrlString(value);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return value == null ? 0 : value.GetHashCode();
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return string.Equals(value, (string)obj);
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
UrlString foo = "abc";
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code and got error. Please reread my question. I have updated the code

Comment: @PanPizza Please apply the thought process. Add this to the class definiton: `Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal u As UrlString) As String 
            Return u.value
        End Operator`

Comment: @GSerg: I tried your suggestion and Visual Studio gives following error: `Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'Phone2.UrlString'.` at this line `a = "http://www.example.com"` of code

Comment: @PanPizza Apparently you replaced one operator with the other. I suggested you add it without deleting the existing one. So that you have both. See [here](http://pastebin.com/FRRNTkzk).

Comment: I would recommend returning null in the implicit operator if the value it's given is null. I'd be confused if I assigned null to a reference type and somehow got an object back anyway.